# simpleCart(js) : Can't view shopping cart on another page

Tags: javascript, html, simplecart

I have two html pages; shop and cart, in both headers I have the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/simpleCart.js"></script>
```

In my shop.html I have this code in the body;

```
<div id="cart" style="clear: both;">
        <a href="cart.html">YOUR CART ( <span class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> )</a>        
    </div>
```

and

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem" style="margin-top:120px;">
                <h1 class="item_name"> Oriental Patterned Maxiskirt</>
                <h1 class="item_price"> PHP2,099</h1>


                <h1 class="size_item_title">SIZE</h1>             
                <ul>
                     <li>
                     <input type="radio" class="item_size" id="s-size1" value="small" name="size1">
                     <label class="sizeLabel" style="background-color:#fff;" for="s-size1">S</label>

                     <div class="size"></div>
                     </li>

                     <li>
                     <input type="radio" class="item_size" id="m-size1" value="medium" name="size1">
                     <label class="sizeLabel" style="background-color:#fff;" for="m-size1">M</label>

                     <div class="size"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                     </li>

                     <li>
                     <input type="radio" class"item_size" id="l-size1" value="large" name="size1">
                     <label class="sizeLabel" style="background-color:#fff;" for="l-size1">L</label>

                     <div class="size"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                     </li>
               </ul> 

               <a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> ADD TO CART </a>
            </div>
```

to add items in my cart; and in my cart.html I have the code

```
<div class="simpleCart_items"></div>
```

My problem is that when I click on "Your Cart" it brings me to an empty page but if i put the code into shop.html like so;

```
<div id="cart" style="clear: both;">
     <a href="cart.html">YOUR CART ( <span class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> )</a>         
</div>  
<div class="simpleCart_items"></div>
```

it shows the cart on that page. So I'm thinking that there's a link problem, but i'm not sure as to how to link both pages together (I thought that putting the simpleCart.js in the header linked the both of them already). If anyone knows why it's not showing on the other page, it'll be such a big help. Thanks

Comment: So, how does the cart get filled? My guess is you did not include the proper JS to fill the `<div class="simpleCart_items"></div>` in your cart.html.

Comment: @glubus I edited my question to show how my cart gets filled. And when you say "you did not include the proper JS" do you mean in the header?

Comment: Looks to me like you're populating the `div` with actual html without javascript. So the 'only' explanation would be that your `href` is not set correctly. Try navigating manually to the `cart.html` and compare the 2 URLS.

Answer (score 0):

- check if both your html pages reside in the same directory.
- check if your cart.html links properly to other libraries required by your system, perhaps jquery.js
- check your console log on cart.html for any errors.